# css + html menu hitbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote some code using different internet sources.  I ran into a problem -
every object that's in the bottom part of the menu cannot be interacted with.
The menu interferes with everything below where the dropdown falls.

```
<style>
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 23px;
}
#nav {
    background-color:1a1a1a;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
#nav_wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: right;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 200px;
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}
#nav ul li a, visited {
    color: #CCC;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 0px solid #222;
    border-top: 0;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
#nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #699;
}
.left-to-right {
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
<html lang="he">
<body  dir-"rtl"><div id="nav">

    <div id="nav_wrapper">
<div>
        <ul <ul  dir="RTL">

            <li> <a href="#">תרמילים</a>

                <ul class="left-to-right">
<!--  <li class="backpacks" id="firstlight-20l"> <a href="/products/firstlight-20l"> FirstLight 20L</a> </li>

                        <li class="backpacks" id="firstlight-30l"> <a href="/products/firstlight-30l"> FirstLight 30L</a> </li>

                        <li class="backpacks" id="firstlight-40l"> <a href="/products/firstlight-40l"> FirstLight 40L</a> </li>-->

                        <li class="backpacks"> <a href="/products/rotation180-professional-Deluxe"> rotation180° Professional 38L Deluxe</a> </li>

                        <li class="backpacks"> <a href="/products/rotation180-horizon"> rotation180° Horizon 34L</a> </li>

                        <li class="backpacks"> <a href="/products/rotation180-panorama"> rotation180° Panorama 22L</a> </li>

<!--                        <li class="backpacks" id="rotation180-travel-away"> <a href="/products/rotation180-travel-away"> rotation180° Travel Away 22L</a> </li>-->

                        <li class="backpacks" id="rotation180-trail"> <a href="/products/rotation180-trail"> rotation180° Trail 16L</a> </li>

                      </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">תיקי מצלמות ספורט</a>

                <ul class="left-to-right">
                    <li><a href="#">GP 1 kit case</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">GP 2 kit case</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">אביזרים</a>

                <ul class="left-to-right">
                    <li><a href="#">r180º Panorama/Horizon Photo Insert</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which dropdown ? explain

Comment: They are right aligned in my PC browser!! OK, Now I get it, you want the menu content to be left.

Comment: Just add `text-align: left;` for `#nav ul ul` in CSS. Let me know if it works.

Comment: In your code is no dropdown. Please show us the relevant code with the dropdown, then we're able to help. The code you provided aligns your menu right, just like you want to.

Comment: @Roman it is not dropdown actually, it seems he created a menu. That is what he meant.

Comment: something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zkb85n18/)???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#nav_wrapper ul ul li{ text-align:left;}
```

you need to add this only: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/617a7kbv/)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use vertical-align for the list elements & text-align for the links.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to the `<ul>` tag of each dropdown and add `text-align: left` to it.

**[FIDDLE Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zkb85n18/)**